# $.ajax method does not call server method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Can someone help in identifying the issue please.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("DeletePrintJobs", "FollowMePrint")',
        //url: "/FollowMePrint/DeletePrintJobs", this does not work
        data: { jobIds: appendJobIds },
        success: function (data) {  },
         error: function (x, y, z) { }
    });
```

If I pass the url using `Url.Action`, it works, but not with the `/{controller}/{action}` . What I suspect is because of the routing it is not working. My Url in browser is `http://localhost/Kiosk/FollowMePrint/DeletePrintJobs`. How to handle the extra `Kiosk` in routing?

Comment: What is Kiosk in your application? An area?

Comment: look at what the full `url` is that's generated and test that.

Comment: I have not used it, but I have heard great things about the VS Route Debugger, just a thought. [Nuget Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiRouteDebugger/)

Comment: @Andrei : Kiosk the website name is IIS.

Comment: Looks like Kiosk is an area name, not the app name. But using `Url.Action()` is the correct approach (it will generate the correct url) so why would you want to hard code the url anyway?